# How to toggle theme in Tailwind (dark mode) with Angular?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, tailwind-css

i made a custom css dark mode in angular. here's the link: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-b99woj)

now i wanted to made the exact same thing with Tailwind.

could anyone help me out?

how to config the global theme colors, i made in the custom css project like this,

```
.theme-light {
  --primary: #2577c1;
  --secondary-bg: #fff;
  --theme: #fff;
  --header-color: rgb(194, 63, 226);
  --route-link-active: #fff;
  --link-color: rgb(85, 80, 80);
  --border-color: rgb(85, 80, 80);
}
.theme-dark {
  --primary: rgb(255, 80, 11);
  --secondary-bg: #424242;
  --theme: #424242;
  --header-color: var(--theme);
  --route-link-active: rgb(255, 80, 11);
  --link-color: #fff;
  --border-color: rgb(28, 214, 28);
}
```

and the app.component.ts was like this,

```
isDarkEnable = false;
presentTheme$ = new BehaviorSubject<string>('theme-light');
constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {
  const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
  if (savedTheme) {
    this.presentTheme$.next(savedTheme);
  }
}
changeTheme() {
  this.presentTheme$.value === 'theme-light'
    ? this.presentTheme$.next('theme-dark')
    : this.presentTheme$.next('theme-light');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', this.presentTheme$.value);
  this.isDarkEnable = !this.isDarkEnable;
}
```

app.component.html

```
<div [class]="(presentTheme$ | async)">
  <header>
    <app-header>
      <a *ngIf="isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">LIGHT</a>
      <a *ngIf="!isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">DARK</a>
    </app-header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</div>
```

the tailwind says that i have to bind the class in the body tag, and i have no idea that how would i do the dark mode with the class binded to the body.

please help me. thank you

Answer (score 3):

Tailwind actually has a way to create custom styles. Once you follow these [install instructions for tailwind](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/angular), you should be able to create your own custom styles inside the `tailwind.config.js` file that is created in your project during the install.

For your custom colors the `tailwind.config.js` file would look something like this:

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    colors: {
      // Light theme colors
      'primary': '#2577c1',
      'secondary-bg': '#fff',
      'theme': '#fff',
      'header-color': '#c23fe2',
      'route-link-active': '#fff',
      'link-color': '#555050',
      'border-color': '#555050',

      // Dark theme colors
      'dark-primary': '#ff500b',
      'dark-secondary-bg': '#424242',
      'dark-theme': '#424242',
      'dark-header-color': '#424242',
      'dark-route-link-active': '#ff500b',
      'dark-link-color': '#fff',
      'dark-border-color': '#1cd61c',
    },
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
};
```

The most important things to note here are the names of the colors, and `darkMode` being set to `'class'`.

The names of the colors (i.e. `'primary'`, `'dark-primary'`) are how you will use these colors in your code, and have `darkMode` set to `'class'` makes sure that you can change your styles using tailwinds `dark:` syntax.

Once you have your config file set up you can bind to the body with `ngClass` and in the end you should have an `index.html` that looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>TestApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico" />
  </head>
  <app-root></app-root>
</html>
```

and an `app.component.html` that looks like this:

```
<body [ngClass]="{ dark: isDarkEnable }">
  <header>
    <app-header>
      <a *ngIf="isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">LIGHT</a>
      <a *ngIf="!isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">DARK</a>
    </app-header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</body>
```

Now you will be able to use `dark:` to change your styles for dark mode either by adding a class to an element like so:

```
<div class="bg-secondary-bg dark:bg-dark-secondary-bg"></div>
```

or by adding the following to a class definition in a css file:

```
.someclass {
  @apply bg-secondary-bg dark:bg-dark-secondary-bg;
}
```

As you can see, we are using the name of the color in the `tailwind.config.js` file (`secondary-bg` and `dark-secondary-bg`) to set the background (`bg`) to the appropriate color.

[Here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) is some more info about dark mode with tailwindcss if you are interested.

Happy Coding! :)

Comment: This only works for components that have no view encapsulation, so everything in the router outlet won't be affected by this.

Answer (score 0):

you might consider using this [tw-colors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tw-colors)

```
const { createThemes } = require('tw-colors');

module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  content: ['./src/**/*.{html,ts}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [
    createThemes({
      light: {
        'primary': '#ff500b',
        'secondary-bg': '#fff',
        'theme': '#fff',
        'header-color': '#c23fe2',
        'route-link-active': '#fff',
        'link-color': '#555050',
        'border-color': '#555050',
      }, 
      dark: {
        'primary': '#2577c1',
        'secondary-bg': '#424242',
        'theme': '#424242',
        'header-color': '#424242',
        'route-link-active': '#ff500b',
        'link-color': '#fff',
        'border-color': '#1cd61c',
      }, 
    })
  ],
};
```

`app.component.html`

```
<body [ngClass]="{ 'theme-dark': isDarkEnable, 'theme-light': !isDarkEnable  }">
  <header>
    <app-header>
      <a *ngIf="isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">LIGHT</a>
      <a *ngIf="!isDarkEnable" (click)="changeTheme()" mode-button style="font-size:30px">DARK</a>
    </app-header>
  </header>

  <main>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </main>
</body>
```

Then you don't need to change the class or use `dark:...` anywhere in your app, switching the body class will change the colors everywhere.
Here is what the markup would look like:

```
<div class='bg-primary'>...</div>
```